# Transform array of objects to nested array of objects

Tags: javascript

Actually I have an array of objects to transform.

```
[  
   { "val1":"2.0" },
   { "val2":"2.0" },
   { "val3":"2.0" },
   { "val1":"4.0" },
   { "val2":"2.0" },
   { "val3":"4.7" },
   { "val1":"4.0" },
   { "val2":"4.0" },
   { "val3":"4.0" }
]
```

I should take every three items and put them in a separate array with a parent item.

I would transform it to this format

```
[  
   [  
      "20190201",
      [  
         { "val1":"2.0" },
         { "val2":"2.0" },
         { "val3":"2.0" }
      ]
   ],
   [  
      "20190202",
      [  
         { "val2":"2.0" },
         { "val3":"2.0" },
         { "val1":"4.0" }
      ]
   ]
]
```

Actually here's how I made

```
const returnData= fileDateName.map((_fileDate: string, _index: number) => {
        return [_fileDate, [
            filteredData[_index],
            filteredData[_index + 1],
            filteredData[_index + 2],
        ]];
    });
```

My actual problem is that my output don't take the next three values but every time it shift one item then take the next values. I think it's because that `_index` value doesn't increment as it should.

```
Index =0 
filteredData[0],
filteredData[1],
filteredData[2],
index=1
filteredData[1],
filteredData[2],
filteredData[3],
...
```

but the iteration should make

```
Index =0 
filteredData[0],
filteredData[1],
filteredData[2],
index=3
filteredData[3],
filteredData[4],
filteredData[5],
...
```

Edit

```
FileDateName= ["20190201","20190202","20190203"]
```

How could it set index value every iteration ?

Comment: where the dates `20190201` and `20190202` come from?

Comment: from `fileDateName` it contains the length of input array /3 value

Comment: Why don't you show us `fileDateName` ?

Comment: i have updated my post

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this using Array#map and Array#slice. Take the index of the dates and multiply it by 3 to find the starting position of where you should take the data.

```js
const dates = [20190201, 20190202, 20190203]
const data=[{"val1":"2.0"},{"val2":"2.0"},{"val3":"2.0"},{"val1":"4.0"},{"val2":"2.0"},{"val3":"4.7"},{"val1":"4.0"},{"val2":"4.0"},{"val3":"4.0"}]

const res = dates.map((date, index)=>{
  const start = index * 3;
  const end = start + 3;
  return [
    date,
    data.slice(start, end)
  ]
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Info from the OP is really fragmentary, but this seems likely to be what they need, although it's not entirely clear. (Side note: Perhaps calculate `start` first and then avoid the second multiplication...)

Comment: I would critique this by saying that you are depending on the dates more than the data, whereas the dates should be generated based on the data. At least from the standpoint of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I would tend to disagree. The OP is mapping the fileDateNames (which in my post is dates) and the question is `How could it set index value every iteration ?`

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
const returnData= fileDateName.map((_fileDate: string, _index: number)
=> {
        if(_index % 3 === 0)  
          return [_fileDate, [
              filteredData[_index],
              filteredData[_index + 1],
              filteredData[_index + 2],
          ]];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly easy task.

Just reduce the array into an array of chunks the size of three items. Along the way, use modular arithmetic to determine when you need to start a new group.

```js
var data = [  
   { "val1": "2.0" },
   { "val2": "2.0" },
   { "val3": "2.0" },
   { "val1": "4.0" },
   { "val2": "2.0" },
   { "val3": "4.7" },
   { "val1": "4.0" },
   { "val2": "4.0" },
   { "val3": "4.0" }
];

console.log(groupData(data, 3, new Date(2019, 1, 1)));

function formatDate(d) {
  return [
    d.getFullYear(),
    ('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2),
    ('00' + d.getDate()).substr(-2),
  ].join('');
}

function groupData(data, size, startDate) {
  return data.reduce((result, item, index) => {
    if (index % size === 0) {
      result.push([ formatDate(startDate), [ item ] ]); // Begin a new group
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1); // Increment the day by 1
    } else {
      result[result.length - 1][1].push(item); // Add item to the last group
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by iterating over your dates array and pushing 3 items with the date to your ouptut array:

```js
const data = [  
   { "val1":"2.0" },
   { "val2":"2.0" },
   { "val3":"2.0" },
   { "val1":"4.0" },
   { "val2":"2.0" },
   { "val3":"4.7" },
   { "val1":"4.0" },
   { "val2":"4.0" },
   { "val3":"4.0" }
];

const dates = ['20190101', '20190201', '20190301'];

const result = dates.reduce((acc, date, i) => {
  acc.push([date, [data[i * 3], data[i * 3 + 1], data[i * 3 + 2]]]);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Are you trying to call acc as a function, like acc() ?

Comment: acc is just the accumulator in the reducer, it is initialized to []

Comment: Do you have more information? The code works fine in the snippet.